# ¿Cómo evitar llevar dato de input en navegación?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, php7

Me encuentro trabajando con una selección que me permite llegar a un formulario de preguntas de acorde a la selección inicial, dicha selección inicial necesita validar un pin. El código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
session_start();
$selectBox1 = $_POST["cServ"]; 
$selectBox2 = $_POST["cJef"];
$pin_obtenido = $_POST['pinWrite'];
$_SESSION['pin_guardado'] = $_POST['pinWrite'];

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "myspw", 
"u233315316_norma035");
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM empresasregistradas WHERE pin = '$pin_obtenido' 
AND rango_empleados='Menos de 50'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
 $filas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
 if($filas>0){

 if ($selectBox1 == "si"  && $selectBox2 == "si") {
header('Location: cuestionario1.php');
}
elseif ($selectBox1 == "si"  && $selectBox2 == "no") {
header('Location: cuestionario2.php');
}
elseif ($selectBox1 == "no"  && $selectBox2 == "no"){
header('Location: cuestionario3.php');
}
elseif ($selectBox1 == "no"  && $selectBox2 == "si"){
header('Location: cuestionario4.php');
}
else {
    header('Location: pre.php');
}

}else {
echo'<script type="text/javascript">
alert("EL PIN ES INCORRECTO");
window.location.href="pre.php";
</script>';
}
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Esto me funciona correctamente y el pin es validado y llevado a la pagina correspondiente para ser introducido al contestar el cuestionario, EL PROBLEMAS ES QUE **Si navego sobre las url accediendo a los cuestionarios 1,2,3 y 4 el SIN validar PIN antes, el PIN aparece cargado en la caja de texto como si se hubiese validado y esto por motivos de seguridad esta mal.** Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: @suri-gangs-halen Si nesecitas que los formularios se recorran secuencialmente, o condicionados a respuestas en los anteriores, el pin puede ajustarse y tener un update (o append) acorde con el camino recorrido de modo que se validen pin inicial y de trayectoria.

Comment: @quevedo Cómo puedo buscar esa información?

Comment: @suri-gangs-halen Si lo que me preguntas es por algún sitio donde puedas informarte sobre manejo secuencial de formularios. No puedo responder porque lo ignoro. Pero, en tu caso, las cuatro condiciones, pueden tener asociado un marcador específico cada una, de modo que sea el "permiso" para revisar cada uno, si dicho marcador no está rediriges al punto de entrada. Cada cuestionario revisa que la condición de entrada se cumpla, en caso negativo redirige a dicho punto.